# linq member has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Upon running the query I have the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException : The member
>   'Application.Product.IsValid' has no supported translation to SQL.

What is wrong with the following query?

Part of product class:

```
public Boolean IsValid
    {
        get { return this.isValid; }
        set
        {
            isValid = value;
        }
    }
```

---

I have a query as follows:

```
 Table<Product> Producttable = dataContext.GetTable<Product>();
            Table<ClientProduct> ClientProducttable = dataContext.GetTable<ClientProduct>();

 var query =
                from product in Producttable where product.IsValid == true
                join clientProduct in ClientProducttable
                on product.ID equals clientProduct.ProductID
                where clientProduct.ClientID == clientID 
                orderby product.Name ascending
                select product;
```

I also get the same error if I do

```
Table<Product> table = dataContext.GetTable<Product>();

        IQueryable<Product> query =
            from row in table
            where row.IsValid == false
            select row;

        return query.ToList<Product>();
```

Comment: Try changing `where product.isValid == true` with `where product.Isvalid == true`. (you referenced a field, now you will reference a property).

Comment: As a side note, you could use the property shortcut to save declaring a backing field since you're getter and setter aren't doing anything exotic: `prop bool IsValid { get; set; };`

Comment: @AgentFire actually `== true` is redundant, just do `product.Isvalid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark your `Isvalid` property with `Column` attribute.

I believe, the Linq-to-sql engine needs to have a `column` attribute in order to look up the database table. As well as its parameters (of the attribute), like ColumnName or alike.